# jquery replacewith() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to clone a template and append it to a div, however, I would like to be able to replace the appended template by another cloned one following the same process of cloning and appending.

HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="temp1">
  <p>This is a template to be cloned</p>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="temp2">
  <p>No, this is another temp that got cloned</p>
</div>
<select id="cloneOptions">
  <option value="0">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">Clone 1</option>
  <option value="2">Clone 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="cloning">Click to clone</button>
<div id="cloned" style="padding:2%;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cloneOptions').on('change',function(){
    if(this.value === "1"){
      $('#cloning').one('click',function() {
        var clone = $('#temp1').clone().attr('class', 'genID');
        alert('Hello');
        $(clone).show();
        $('#cloned').append(clone);
        if($('#cloned div').hasclass('genID')){
          $('#cloned div').replacewith(clone);
        }                
        $('#cloneOptions').val('0');
      });
    }
    else if(this.value === "2"){
      $('#cloning').one('click',function() {
        var clone = $('#temp2').clone().attr('class', 'genID');
        alert('Hello');
        if($('#cloned div').hasclass('genID')){
          alert('Clone');
          $('#cloned div').replacewith(clone);
        }
        $(clone).show();
        $('#cloneOptions').val('0');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Please refer to my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sunit2016/nLstx3so/1/

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Capitalize the `w` in `replacewith`. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLstx3so/2/). This question is off-topic for SO and should be closed as a typo. It will not be helpful for other users.

Comment: How could I miss it...i feel so stupid myself, anyway, thanks for the observation.

Comment: How could you miss it? You obviously didn't look in browser console (F12) to look for errors thrown

Comment: Yes, I didn't check the console, my bad...

Answer (score 1):

Change `replacewith` to `$('#genID').replaceWith(clone)`; 
Javascript is case sensitive.